# Order by number returned from the function in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find an answer but I can't find an answer on this and I can't figure it out either.

The question is: Is it possible to order posts by number from highest to lowest in wp_query but if that number is returned from the function?

So the users have abilities to post comments with the ratings in the post, and rating is recorded in comment meta field `rate`, so there is a function that collect ratings and get the average rating of the post.

```
function gt3_get_average_ratings($id) {
    $comment_array = get_approved_comments($id);
    $count = 1;
    if ($comment_array) {
        $i = 0;
        $total = 0;
        foreach($comment_array as $comment){
            $rate = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'rate');
            if(isset($rate[0]) && $rate[0] > 0) {
                $i++;
                $total += $rate[0];
            }
        }
        if($i > 0) {
            $total_tmp = $total/$i;
            $show_total_rate = round($total_tmp, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            if ($total_tmp > $show_total_rate) {
                $show_total_rate = $show_total_rate . '_5';
            }
        }
        if($i == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return $show_total_rate;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function only return numbers like `5` or `3` or `2`

And I can't figure out how to use the function `gt3_get_average_ratings` to sort posts in wp_query by highest number or top rated like this in example

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post',
    'orderby' => gt3_get_average_ratings,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This or any other examples I tried don't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: _"Is it possible to order posts by number from highest to lowest in wp_query but if that number is returned from the function?"_ - no, it is not. Any such PHP function would be called _before_ anything gets passed to the database. You will either need to see to it that you have your average rating stored directly as a meta value of the posts themselves; or you will have to select _all_ posts each time, and then order them afterwards in your own code, outside of the query. (The latter would of course cause additional problems with stuff like pagination.)

Comment: Thank you for reply, this is how I made it work, I made a function to store meta value of average rating in post it self and update every time someone make a comment.